# product flavor names cannot collide with build type names

Tags: android-studio, android-build-flavors

I have created two build flavor one is debug and another one is release. 
Step 1. Go project structure in add flavor.
step 2. Click on OK .

Now i am facing error like **

> "product flavor names cannot collide with build type names"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Build flavor name and build type name are same. Like build type `release` or `debug` or flavor names are debug and release.

Do rename your build flavor like `dev` or `prod`.